# K8s issue pulling from docker private repository

Tags: kubernetes, jhipster, dockerhub

I have a Jhipster application which I want to deploy to Kubernetes. I used the `jhipster kubernetes` command to create all the k8s objects and I provided an Docker Hub repository in which to push them. The Docker Hub repository is a private one.

The deployment object looks like:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: demodevices
    namespace: demo
spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: demodevices
            version: 'v1'
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                app: demodevices
                version: 'v1'
        spec:
            initContainers:
                - name: init-ds
                  image: busybox:latest
                  command:
                      - '/bin/sh'
                      - '-c'
                      - |
                          while true
                          do
                            rt=$(nc -z -w 1 demodevices-postgresql 5432)
                            if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                              echo "DB is UP"
                              break
                            fi
                            echo "DB is not yet reachable;sleep for 10s before retry"
                            sleep 10
                          done
            containers:
                - name: demodevices-app
                  image: myRepo/demo:demodevices-1.0.0
                  env: ...
                  resources: ...
                  ports: ...
                  readinessProbe: ...
                  livenessProbe: ...
            imagePullSecrets:
            - name: regcred
```

Because I used a private Docker Hub repo, I added the `imagePullSecret`. The secret is created and deployed to k8s.

When applying the file, in the pods I see the following messages:

```
 Warning  Failed     <invalid> (x4 over <invalid>)  kubelet, k8node1   Failed to pull image "busybox:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/busybox/manifests/latest: unauthorized: incorrect username or password
 Warning  Failed     <invalid> (x4 over <invalid>)  kubelet, k8node1   Error: ErrImagePull
 Normal   BackOff    <invalid> (x6 over <invalid>)  kubelet, k8node1   Back-off pulling image "busybox:latest"
 Warning  Failed     <invalid> (x6 over <invalid>)  kubelet, k8node1   Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

As I understood, it tries do pull the busybox:latest image using the credentials for the private repository. The expected result is to pull the busybox:latest without errors and pull my custom image from my private repo. How to fix the above issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is not connected to the fact you are using `imagePullSecret`.

[Review](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#creating-a-secret-with-a-docker-config) the process you used to create your secret, here is an example:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry anyname \
--docker-server=docker.io \
--docker-username=<username> \
--docker-password=<password> \
--docker-email=<email>
```

I have reproduced your case and I have the same error when I create the secret with wrong information.

Comment: note that if your password contains a $ you have to escape it using \$

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the Private Repo into the Docker In-Secure Registry. Also have you tried logging in into your private repo using docker login? When you do so it creates an entry into login creds.
Try doing a manual pull using docker login and docker pull/run. If this works it must work with K8s too.

Comment: I don't know what is the  Docker In-Secure Registry. I can manually pull and run the image after docker login, so no issue on this side. One thing thou: when creating the  secret, I need to provide some parameters. The one I'm unsure is `--docker-server` because I don't know the format of docker hub for this param. Now I have set repository

Comment: Here is an example on how to create the secret: `kubectl create secret docker-registry anyname --docker-server=docker.io --docker-username=<username> --docker-password=<password> --docker-email=<email>`

Comment: Do you run things behind a corporate  proxy ?

Comment: @SriniM no, I don't have any proxy.

Comment: Please have a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55773755/dockerhub-in-kubernetes-give-unauthorized-incorrect-username-or-password-with-r

Comment: @mWatney it worked using your I can accept it if you post an answer